# Does NSNotification somehow use threads internally?

Tags: iphone, ios5, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

NSNotification is non-blocking call. Does it mean it runs threads internally somehow ? If not what happens actually: when observer receives the event it executes the handler then the observee continues ? In that case non-blocking is actually fake ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure but I believe it is directly tied into the event loop handling code. I don't think it spins up a thread.

Comment: I wouldn't say "fake." I think because it is weaved into the event loop, it can do everything it needs to do while still letting regular events get processed normally.